# Filename stripped of prefix in form data

Tags: reactjs, go, multipartform-data

I am sendind files from js to my golang server:

```js
for (var value of formData.values()) {
   console.log(value);

}
// File {name: 'img/<hash_key>.png', lastModified: 1635043863231, lastModifiedDate: Sat Oct 23 2021 23:51:03 GMT-0300 (Brasilia Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 969, …}
// ...

var request = new Request( serverEndpoint, { body: formData, method: "POST", ... })

return fetch(request).then(response => { ... })
```

In my golang server, I am using the following code to deal with multipart form data from a request to read files

```golang
if err := r.ParseMultipartForm(32 << 20); err != nil {
    ...
}

for _, fileHeader := range r.MultipartForm.File["files"] {
    ...
}
```

I expected to read the files in Go with the same filenames, like `img/<hash_key>.png`
but my server is reading multipart-form to the following struct:

```
f = {*mime/multipart.Form | 0xc000426090} 
├── Value = {map[string][]string} 
└── File = {map[string][]*mime/multipart.FileHeader} 
    ├── 0 = files -> len:1, cap:1
    │   ├── key = {string} "files"
    │   └── value = {[]*mime/multipart.FileHeader} len:1, cap:1
    │       └── 0 = {*mime/multipart.FileHeader | 0xc000440000} 
    │           ├── Filename = {string} "<hash_key>.png" // notice how FileName is missing 'img/' prefix
    │           └── ...
    └── ...
```

I am trying to figure out how this is happening and how to prevent this strip prefix as I need this prefix to correctly resolve upload path for my files

***Edit:***

Closer inspection revealed that my server IS in fact getting the files with the correct name. After calling `r.ParseMultipartForm(32 << 20)`, I get the following in `r.Body.src.R.buf`:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary1uanPdXqZeL8IPUH
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="img/upload.svg" 
                                           ---- notice the img/ prefix
Content-Type: image/svg+xml

<svg height="512pt" viewBox= ...
```

However, in `r.MultipartForm.File["files"][0].FileName`, it shows as `upload.svg`

Comment: I'd like to think this is true.. however, a minimal test tells me otherwise as I was able to determine my server IS getting the file named as `img/<filename>.png`. i'll edit the question to add more context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directory is removed in [in Part.FileName()](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/8dbf3e9393400d72d313e5616c88873e07692c70/src/mime/multipart/multipart.go#L82-L84):

```
// RFC 7578, Section 4.2 requires that if a filename is provided, the
// directory path information must not be used.
return filepath.Base(filename)
```

Workaround Part.FileName() by parsing the content disposition header directly.

```
for _, fileHeader := range r.MultipartForm.File["files"] {
    _, params, _ := mime.ParseMediaType(fileHeader.Header.Get("Content-Disposition"))
    filename := params["filename"]
    if filename == "" {
         // TODO: Handle unexpected content disposition 
         // header (missing header, parse error, missing param).
    }
```

Comment: this solution worked! thanks! this bugged me seriously, because I could have sworn I made successful uploads just the day before without having this issue... but well guess my memory failed me